# unable write json array data to text file in PHP codeigniter

Tags: json, file

This is my code

```
$encodedString = json_encode($arrData);
            pr($encodedString);
            if ( ! write_file('/documents/stanford_data.txt', $encodedString))
            {
                echo '<br /><br />Unable to write the file<br />';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<br /><br />File written!<br />';
            }
```

Although i changed the permission of entire project folder, the file not written. Why is that? .Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: is it throwing any error? check the path really exists

Comment: path exists. Magically it wrote to another file in the same path once. When i tried with this new file its not writing

Answer (score 0):

Try below one,

```
write_file('/documents/stanford_data.txt', $encodedString, 'c');
```

Described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).